# Forecasting on multivariate time series containing quaternions

Tags: lstm, sequence, multivariate-distribution

I have a multivariate time series containing 3D position data ($x,y,z)$ and orientation data (as [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)) obtained from motion sensors.
My goal is to forecast the future position/orientation, and for this I'm looking into use sequence models, esp. LSTMs.

A quaternion has 4 elements, one of them denoting the real/scalar part (say $q_w$) and the other three denoting the imaginary/vector part (say $q_x, q_y, q_z$). So my time series has 7 columns in total.

My question: Considering that quaternion elements only jointly have a physical meaning (spatial rotations), is it reasonable to apply multivariate forecasting to data in its current format, where $q_w, q_x, q_y, q_z$ are stored as different variables?
Quaternions are the most compact way to denote such rotations but I still have some doubts about whether I'm neglecting the physical dependency of different quaternion elements by treating them as separate variables. Any experience/insight would be great.

**Edit:** [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60315/classification-of-orientation) answer suggests converting from quaternions to Euler angles but this brings a discontinuity for in my data, where there is a jump from 180 to -180 degrees. So not sure if that's a good idea.
Another suggestion given [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36370/how-to-learn-3d-orientations-reliably) is to use the forward and right vector (not sure why not just take the direction vector?) instead of any of the other rotation formalisms.